# how to avoid sonar "Resouces should be closed" blocker warning

Tags: java, sonarqube

I don't want to close RandomAccessFile immediately, but it will warn "Resources should be closed" when sonar scan. How to avoid this? Example code like followings:

```
public class AccessFileTest {
    private static RandomAccessFile accessFile;
    private static FileChannel fileChannel;
    private static long maxFileLength = 1024 * 1024;
    private static long currentFileLenth = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            write("test");
        }
    }

    private static void write(String text) {
        try {
            if (accessFile == null) {
                accessFile = new RandomAccessFile("", "rw");
                fileChannel = accessFile.getChannel();
            }
            ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(text.getBytes());
            fileChannel.write(buffer);
            closeAccessFileIfNeed(text.getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void closeAccessFileIfNeed(byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
        currentFileLenth += bytes.length;
        if (currentFileLenth >= maxFileLength) {
            accessFile.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**can you try this operation in  try with resource**

In here

when you are using try with resource , close() is automatically called by jVM , manually you don't need to do anything

Without using try with resource, Sonar is saying `Resources should be closed`
meaning is , you should close it manually , inside finally   block

```
 try (RandomAccessFile accessFile = new RandomAccessFile("", "rw")) {

      FileChannel fileChannel = accessFile.getChannel();
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
```

Comment: @bird man , I think , this will be the answer , if it is not add me comment to explain ,Thanks

Comment: no, I mean that I don't want to close it immediately in this block,  there are some special logic to close it later, for example, when I call the method to write a file one time by one time, want to close the file after the file reach a fixed length.  Have some tips to avoid the sonar scan?

Comment: Have you run this

Comment: Could you please run this block and let me know

Comment: Actually , in your question , mentioned  `how to avoid sonar “Resouces should be closed” blocker warning` and I already have given explanation and how to resolved that , If it is okay you can take it

Comment: In your question `I don't want to close RandomAccessFile immediately` actually  this not trying to close it immediate, close() is automatically called after your process

Comment: sorry, I add the completed code again, you can see it